# R Leaflet: popup offset without using markers

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way to offset popups (created independent of markers) in the R version of leaflet?

Experimenting with popup options I've managed to control the offset in X like this:

```
popup_options <- popupOptions()
popup_options$offset <- x
```

This works to offset popups created with addPopups by x.  I've tried these ideas:

```
popup_options$offset <- c(x, y)
popup_options$offset <- "L.point(x,y);"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this works!  Somehow it gets recognised as a 'point' type by leaflet.

```
popup_options$offset <- list(c(x, y))
```